# Запятая в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

в сочетании "но смотри не переусердствуй" не нужно обосабливать "смотри"? И если нет, то чем является "смотри не переусердствуй" : составным глагольным сказуемвм или составным именным сказуемым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Но смотри не переусердствуй.***

Это осложненная форма простого глагольного сказуемого (ПГС). В него входит глагольная частица ***смотри***.

Пример: ***Смотри не урони вазу.***

Материал из учебника Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка".